# Vuejs composition API - property changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm curious about passing props into setup and what are best practices to update variables/templates based on property changes.

I'm curious about `reactive` and `computed`.

For example:

```
setup(props) {
  // Setup global config settings
  const config = computed(() => {
    return {
      // See if the component is disabled
      isDisabled: props.disabled, // (1)

      // Test for rounded
      isRounded: props.rounded // (2)
    }
  })

  return { config }
}
```

1. Should `config.isDisabled` and `config.isRounded` be wrapped in their own `computed` function as they are both different and independent? However, it is easy to just stick them into one big function. What is best practice in this regard?
2. Does the entire `config` function evaluate once a single property changes within the function or can it recognize the change and update what is required?
3. Per docs, `reactive` is deeply reactive and used for objects, however, I've noticed it doesn't update to property changes. Therefore, I've been treating it more like `data` in Vue 2. Am I missing something or is this correct treatment?

Answer (score 1):

1. You do not have to wrap props with `computed` at all, as they [should be already reactive and immutable](https://composition-api.vuejs.org/api.html#setup).

   You also do not have to return `config` from your setup function as all props passed to your component should be automatically exposed to your template.
2. The `computed` function is evaluated only once and then Vue3 uses `Proxy` to observe changes to values and update only what's required. If you need to run a function every time a property changes you can use [watchEffect](https://composition-api.vuejs.org/api.html#watcheffect).
3. Vue3 `reactive` is actually deep and works fine on objects. It should track all changes, unless you are trying to change the original object (the target of `reactive` function).

Comment: 1 - in my case they need to be - I eliminated some code for clarity sake
2 - is the entire proxy evaluated or just a portion I imagine if I had a object(styling) as a computed prop it would evaluate the entire property on a single change (more or less my question)